# Unable to inherit hasMany property

Tags: inheritance, grails, grails-orm, has-many

I'm currently migrating my grails code from version 2.5.6 to 3.3.9. On 3.3.9, I observed this weird behaviour:

There's an abstract class (in src/main/groovy) which contains a hasMany relationship.

```
package srcFolder

import grailsthree.TestSimpleClass

abstract class TestSuperClass {
    String superClassValue

    static hasMany = [simples: TestSimpleClass]
}
```

A domain class which inherits this abstract class.

```
package grailsthree

import srcFolder.TestSuperClass

class TestSubClass extends TestSuperClass{
    String subClassValue

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

In the Bootstrap, call the addTo on the hasMany property of subclass,

```
package grailsthree

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        TestSimpleClass testSimpleClass = new TestSimpleClass(simpleClassValue: 'simpleClassValue').save()
        TestSubClass testSubClass = new TestSubClass(subClassValue: 'subClassValue')
        testSubClass.addToSimples(testSimpleClass)
        testSubClass.save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Got following error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: grailsthree.TestSubClass.addToSimples() is applicable for argument types: (grailsthree.TestSimpleClass) values: [grailsthree.TestSimpleClass : 1]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:71)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128)
    at grailsthree.BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1099)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:541)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:534)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:510)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.boostrap.DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.callInit(DefaultGrailsBootstrapClass.java:74)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.context.GrailsConfigUtils.executeGrailsBootstraps(GrailsConfigUtils.java:65)
    at org.grails.plugins.web.servlet.context.BootStrapClassRunner.onStartup(BootStrapClassRunner.groovy:53)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:263)
    at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.onApplicationEvent(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:393)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:347)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:883)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:146)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
    at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
    at grailsthree.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
```

Seems like on Grails 3.3.9, the sub-class is not inheriting the abstract class hasMany property. This is working fine for Grails 2.5.6.

Do we need to do any other handling in Grails 3.3.9 for this scenario?

Comment: annotate you superclass with `@grails.gorm.annotation.Entity`

Comment: @injecteer I tried that as well, but it creates a table in the DB corresponding to my abstract super class. My main motive is to use this abstract class to inherit the properties in the sub-domain classes.

Comment: creation of a table for the parent class and use of discriminator field --> this is how inheritance works in GORM. You can specify the explicit `tableName` in `mapping{...}` though, but the discriminator `_clazz` field will still be created in the table

Comment: @injecteer, yeah I get that. It's just that I don't want it to be treated as a domain class. As I mentioned, my intention to use this abstract class is for inheriting the properties in the sub-domain classes.

Comment: you can create a `trait` instead of a super class

Comment: @injecteer I tried that as well, but still could not avoid the above-mentioned error.

Comment: You have to implement that method in your trait - as simple as that. GORM's dynamic methods can not be injected into a non-entity.

Comment: @injecteer Well, for the time being I've created domain classes for these POGO classes. In order to make sure these domains are not persistable, I've added the static mapWith block set to "none".